# How to select items from a List of series till it reaches a break

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of numbers following an arithmetic sequence with a gap in between. For example `[0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,146,148,150,152,154,156,158,160,162,164,166,168,170,172,174,176,178,180]`

I want to select the numbers till the gap is reached. In this example `[0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26]`.

I have written this and I was wondering if this can be simplified using LINQ

```cs
double commonDifference = 2;
 
List<double> oldList = new List<double>() {
  0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 
  146, 148, 150, 152, 154, 156, 158, 160, 162, 164, 166, 168, 170, 172, 174, 176, 178, 180 
};

List<double> newList = new List<double>();

for (int i = 0; i < oldList.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (oldList[i + 1] - oldList[i] == commonDifference)
    {
        newList.Add(oldList[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        newList.Add(oldList[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the common difference predetermined?

Comment: Why is oldList[i] - oldList[i+1] ? it's always be -2  in this case.

Comment: If you look at all the answers using Linq, I think you might agree that they all make the solution more complicated and/or harder to read. So: Don't use Linq for this. Linq isn't the magic solution for *all* problems involving collections!

Comment: Yes the common difference is predetermined.
And yes it will be It will be oldList[i+1]  - oldList[i]. I made a mistake.

Comment: FYI if there isn't a gap this will not include the last number.

Comment: @wolfe1947 Please do not amend the question's code. The answers are reflecting to the original code, not to the newest one.

Comment: @PeterCsala It is perfectly OK for the OP to update the question if there was a typo that was pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1XQyf6):

```
var arr = new [] {0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,146,148,150,152,154,156,158,160,162,164,166,168,170,172,174,176,178,180};
var res = arr.TakeWhile(x => x <= arr.Aggregate((p,q) => p != q - 2 ? p : q)) ;
 res.Dump();
```

Comment: You could actually do the aggregate first to get the break point and then use that in the TakeWhile which would reduce the complexity from polynomial to linear.

Comment: @juharr, Isn't it what I did?

Comment: No you're doing the `Aggregate` inside of the `TakeWhile`.  I'm saying do it first and assign the result to a variable and then use that variable in the `TakeWhile`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try looping while getting `difference` from the first items; let's generalize the routine:

```
private static IEnumerable<double> UpToGap(IEnumerable<double> data) {
  if (null == data)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data)); 

  double difference = 0;
  double prior = 0;
  long count = 0;

  // Math.Abs: when working with floating point (double)
  // we should compare with tolerance, say 1e-8
  foreach (int item in data) 
    if (count < 2 || Math.Abs(item - prior - difference) < 1e-8) {
      yield return item;

      count += 1;
      difference = item - prior;
      prior = item;          
    } 
    else
      break;    
}
```

Now you can exploit it:

```
   using System.Linq;

   ...


   List<double> newList = UpToGap(oldList).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
List<double> oldList = new List<double>() { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 146, 148, 150, 152, 154, 156, 158, 160, 162, 164, 166, 168, 170, 172, 174, 176, 178, 180 };
var newList = oldList
    .Select((item, index) => (item, index))
    .Where(item => item.index + 1 < oldList.Count)
    .TakeWhile<(double current, int idx)>(item => item.current - oldList[item.idx + 1] == commonDifference)
    .Select(item => item.current)
    .ToList();
```

Explanation:

1. The first `Select` decomposes (deconstruction) the iterator into an `item`(double) and an `index` (int).
2. Without the `break` condition you would need to use `Where`, but because of early exit you should use the `TakeWhile`.
   2.1) Here you need to deconstruct the ValueTuple `(double current, int idx)` in the generic type parameter of the `TakeWhile`. If you would do it inside the `TakeWhile`'s predicate then it won't compile.
3. The second `Select` is needed to get rid of the `index` from the result.

---

UPDATE #1: I've added a new `Where` clause to my proposed solution because as juharr has pointed out it could throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` by over indexing the collection.

---

UPDATE #2: The original author of the question has fixed a bug in his/her algorithm. The newest code to reflect those changes:

```cs
List<double> oldList = new List<double>() { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 146, 148, 150, 152, 154, 156, 158, 160, 162, 164, 166, 168, 170, 172, 174, 176, 178, 180 };
var newList = oldList
    .Select((item, index) => (item, index))
    .Where(item => item.index + 1 < oldList.Count)
    .TakeWhile<(double current, int idx)>(item => oldList[item.idx + 1] - item.current == commonDifference)
    .Select(item => item.current)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if there isn't a gap, like with `{2, 4, 6}` because you don't check to make sure `idx + 1` is less than the size of the list.

Comment: Also you have the subtraction backwards which will result in a -2 and thus select no items.

Comment: @juharr Your first observations is correct. I did overlook the exit condition of the for loop: `for (int i = 0; i < oldList.Count - 1; i++)` I've amended my proposed solution.

Comment: @juharr Even though I do agree with your second observation I will not fix the code. The original post had the same issue. So I did not want to change the algorithm that was provided. I tried to come up with an Linq equivalent of the original for loop.

Comment: The OP fixed that issue in the post so it should really be fixed in any answers that also have it.

Comment: You really haven't fixed the index going out of range as you need to handle it in the `TakeWhile` condition.  Basically all the values will pass the `Where` as the index will always be less than the `Count`.  You need something like `item => item.idx == oldList.Count - 1 || item.current - oldList[item.idx + 1] == commonDifference`

Comment: @juharr fixed the mentioned issue by checking `item.index + 1 < oldList.Count` in the `Where` clause.

Comment: That's going to exclude the last item then.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement you own extension method and move from one element to another in more efficient way by using enumerator implementation.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> TakeUntilFirstGap(this IEnumerable<int> values)
{
    using (var e = values.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (e.MoveNext() == false)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        var first = e.Current;

        if (e.MoveNext() == false)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        var previous = e.Current;

        yield return first;
        yield return previous;
        
        var originalGap = previous - first;
        while(e.MoveNext)
        {
            if (e.Current - previous != originalGap)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            yield return e.Current;

            previous = e.Current
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var withoutGap = values.TakeUntilFirstGap();
```

Comment: `if (e.Current - previous != maxGap)` is safier than `if (e.Current - previous > maxGap)`

Comment: Maybe add a little bit more explanation? first time i read this i was like 'this seems overly complicated' then i read it some more and felt more understanding.

Comment: `if (!e.MoveNext()) yield break;` instead of `if (e.MoveNext() == false)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, although Linq queries can be fancy sometimes they do use more than one iterator. This would be a case where a simple foreach would be just as readable, maintainable and additionally slightly more performant, since you're just iterating through the list once.

For example, i liked the approach of @presi

`var newList = oldList.Zip(oldList.Skip(1), (previous, item) => new {previous, item}).Where(x => x.previous - x.item == commonDifference).Select(s => s.item).ToList();`

But as you can see, `oldList` is iterated in the `.Zip` method, and again when it calls `oldList.Skip(1)`

You can always stick it into a function or extension method yourself. Here's another such example:

```cs
    public static void Main()
    {
        double commonDifference = 2;
        List<double> oldList = new List<double>()
        {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 146, 148, 150, 152, 154, 156, 158, 160, 162, 164, 166, 168, 170, 172, 174, 176, 178, 180};
        List<double> newList = new List<double>();
        foreach (var v in UpToGap(oldList, commonDifference))
        {
            Console.Write(v + " ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("> Done");
    }

    public static IEnumerable<double> UpToGap(IList<double> oldList, double diff) // Note this could be an extension method aswell
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < oldList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (oldList[i] + diff == oldList[i + 1])
                yield return oldList[i]; // Return items in an iterator
            else
            {
                yield return oldList[i]; // Return the last item, before the gap
                yield break; // Stop the iterator and return
            }
        }
    }
```

```
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 
> Done
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/AEzXO3

This uses iterators with the yield keyword which linq extensively uses so its good to know about.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators

This also shows what defered execution means, which could be both an advantage and disadvantage (depending on what you want of course) when using linq.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-example

Answer (score -1):

The main thing is to find out what differentiate the 1st group of numbers from the 2nd. As we get this, it will be easy to construct a query. As far as I see, a) any member of the 1st group is smaller than any member of the 2nd group by at least 100; and b) the pairs of numbers in the group differs by 2. So let's "convert" this conditions into a LINQ form:

```
var firstGroup = oldList
    .Where(
        e => oldList.Any(e2 => e2 - e > 100)
        && oldList.Any(e2 => Math.Abs(e2 - e) == 2))
    .ToList();
```